# different print.gap value for specific column

Tags: r, printing, formatting, output

Is there any way to have a different print.gap for a particular column?

Example data:

```
dd <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 1:5, col3 = I(letters[1:5]))
print (dd, quote=F, right=T, print.gap=5)
```

Output with print.gap=5:

```
      col1     col2     col3
1        1        1        a
2        2        2        b
3        3        3        c
4        4        4        d
5        5        5        e
```

Desired output (print.gap mix, first two with print.gap=5, third with print.gap=12)

```
      col1     col2            col3
1        1        1               a
2        2        2               b
3        3        3               c
4        4        4               d
5        5        5               e
```

I realise this may not be achievable with any change of the print statement, but perhaps some have an alternative method or suggestion. The output is to be saved in a text file. Also please note, the solution should be flexible enough to not just increase the gap for the last column, it could be any column, or multiple columns with different print.gaps in a data frame.

Comment: add `dd$col3 <- paste(substring("       ", length(dd$col3)), dd$col3)` in between your 2 lines

Comment: @HubertL - although that is a destructive change, maybe printing after doing the alteration inside `transform()` might be nice.

Comment: Thanks Hubert, just tried it but does not seem to change anything unless I increase the white spaces in the substring substantially. I guess what you are trying to do is add white spaces in front of the third column data, which is an idea, but Id kind of like to have a more elegant way. Ill have a look at transform.

Comment: try with `print(transform(dd,col3=paste(substring("       ", length(col3)), col3)), quote=F, right=T, print.gap=5)` as suggested by @thelatemail, and yes increase number of space to 7 since SO comment removed them

Comment: Aha, okay, works now ... just saw the last bit of your comment about the extra spaces ... Thanks Hubert.

Comment: Thanks Henrik, but xtable (as far as I have read) outputs only html or latex format. All I want is plain text. Hubert's suggestion is primitive but works well enough for my current primitive purposes.

Comment: You could expand it to be flexible to each column - `rbind( data.frame(lapply(dd, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE), substring("lotsofspaceshere", 1, c(1,7,12)) )`

Comment: Also an interesting method, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a way to do this by defining a "proper" alternative print method, but here's a hackish solution that can be used to adjust each column width independently.

```
rbind(
  data.frame(lapply(dd, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
  substring("                       ", 1, c(1,7,12))
)
#  col1    col2         col3
#1    1       1            a
#2    2       1            b
#3    3       1            c
#4    4       1            d
#5    5       2            e
#6    6       2            f
#7    7       2            g
#8    8       2            h
```